# XML UTF8 charset bounds

Tags: xml, swift, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm working on a XML Library to more fully learn what it is all about. I've ran into needing to escape and validate strings for XML. Looking around people generally just mention `&` and the quotes and `<,>`.

Digging around I found the actual spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets
which states:

```
Char    ::=       #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

Great, perfectly laid out on valid characters. My question is `UTF-8` is 8 bit blocks (code units?) which would max out at decimal value of 256. If I'm strictly using `UTF-8` strings everything will be under the `#xD7FF` range and nothing in the final range.

It seems to me using `UTF-8` doing a bounds check on the upper ranges is meaningless, I know character sets/unicode can be full of gotchas, is there something I'm missing?

For example, I'm using Swift. So if I go

```
let someString = "abcdefg"
for char in someString.utf8 {
//  char is a UTF8.CodeUnit which is a type alias to UInt8, 
//  comparing a UInt8 to a value of something over 256 is just silly?
}
```

I'm assuming those upper ranges are for `UTF-16`+?

Comment: The XML spec is written to process data in terms of Unicode codepoints, not bytes of any particular encoding, like UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.  If you have UTF data, you have to convert its code unit sequences to UTF-32 code units (aka Unicode codepoints) before processing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#xA`, `#xE000`, `#x10000` etc in the XML specification are [Unicode Scalar Values](http://unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value) (aka Unicode codepoints, excluding the high-surrogate and low-surrogate codepoints reserved for UTF-16).  That is what you get when enumerating the [`unicodeScalars`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1539070-unicodescalars) view of a string:

```
for unicode in someString.unicodeScalars {
    let value = unicode.value // an `UInt32`

    // ....
}
```

Then you can test the Unicode scalar value for equality:

```
if value == 0x10000 {

}
```

Or for containment in a range:

```
if 0xE000...0xFFFD ~= value {

}
```

Or in a switch/case statement:

```
switch value {
case 0x0A, 0x0D:
    // ...
case 0xE000...0xFFFD:
    // ...
default:
    // ...
}
```

When enumerating the `utf8` view:

```
for char in someString.utf8 { }
```

You will get a sequence of UTF-8 code units (`UInt8`) in the range
0 ... 255, and each Unicode scalar value is represented by 1, 2, 3
or 4 UTF-8 code units.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.